# Changing %20 in url to - Angular

Tags: angularjs

I am building a MEAN website. Now I have some data I get from my mongoDB. And I am using wildcards to change between data in my URL. Now I succeeded with getting the data from the database correctly, but when data in the db has spaces between it, it places a %20 between the text.

I've already tried by using the replace() and decodeURI, but this would not work.

What I want is to change the %20 to '-' if the data.city has spaces between it

This is my angular controller:

```
getData.getCity().then(function(response){

$scope.items = response.data;

var keepGoing = true;
for(var i = 0; i < $scope.items.length; i++){
  var data = $scope.items[i];
  if(keepGoing) {
    if (angular.lowercase($routeParams.name) == angular.lowercase(data.city)) {

      keepGoing = false;
      $scope.selectedItem = data;
     }
    } 
  }
});
```

Comment: instead of replacing %20 have you just tried replacing a space?

Comment: I have, also not working

Comment: It's obviously angular making the substitution. Why not do the replace when you pull the data from the db before you send it to angular?

Comment: Could you attach code related to your issue? Finding selected item in resultset doesn't affect encoding, propably view contains something that forces angular to make this substitution.